# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol (simple code)

Tags: c++

this is a pretty simple code that just is coming up with an error even though I have it written the same way other people doing the same code have it

> 1>assigntment5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl promptForString(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?promptForString@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>c:\users\aweb\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Assignment5\Debug\Assignment5.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

the .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "anw65_Library.h"

using namespace std;

string promptForString(string prompt);

int main()
{
string name = promptForString("What is the filename?: ");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

the .h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static string promptFromString(string prompt)
{
string filename;
cout << prompt;
cin >> filename;
return filename;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never define `prompt**For**String`, you defined `prompt**From**String`.  Spelling matters.  Also:

1. Why are you defining functions in your .h file?  Just declare them there and define them in the .cpp file (unless they're templates).
2. Don't put `using namespace <whatever>` in a header file.  You're just mucking up the global namespace of whatever includes your header.
3. You don't need to mark that function as `static`.

Comment: I am sorry for being mediocre. It's an exercise for an intro class and he wants us to learn about creating our own headers. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: @user2097783: No no, I wouldn't say that.  everyone starts somewhere.  I didn't mean to come off as harsh.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
string promptForString(string prompt);
```

In your .cpp file is causing issues. It's forward delcaring a function with *external* linkage. However, the function your header is:

```
static string promptFromString(string prompt)
{
...
```

The important part here is the `static`. `static` means it has *internal* linkage. Either get rid of the `static`, or get rid of the forward declaration, because a function can't have both internal and external linkage.

Edit: also, Ed S. made a good find with your typo.

Answer (score 0):

you call `promptForString()` from your main function while you have `promptFromString()` defined in `.h` file.

You might want to change one of the definitions.